# How to join two tables using Criteria API if join relationship is on EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, relational-database, criteria-api

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity 
public class EventOrderLine {

  @EmbeddedId   private EventOrderLineId id;

}

@Embeddable
public class EventOrderLineId implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "eventid")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Event event;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "orderlineid")
  @JsonIgnore
  private OrderLine orderLine;

}


@Entity   
public class OrderLine {

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "orderlineid")
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<EventOrderLine> eventOrderLines = new ArrayList<>()

}
```

Basically I'm trying to join the two tables via the Criteria API but having issues since this is what I want to do:

```
Root eventOrderLine = criteriaQuery.from(EventOrderLine.class);
Join orderLine = eventOrderLine.join("orderLine");
```

Of course this give me this issue since the mapping isn't directly on the entities themselves:

```
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [orderLine] on this ManagedType [com.EventOrderLine]
```

I've been trying to tweak the join to drill into the embeddedId but not sure if I need to go a step further and modify how my entities are mapped. I feel like it's probably something simple I'm missing but having trouble finding this specific question.

Comment: Have you tried `eventOrderLine.join("id").join("event")`?

Comment: I believe this is the right solution! I knew it was something simple. If you make this comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event` field is a member of `EventOrderLineId` and not `EventOrderLine`. In your criteria query, you first need to navigate to `id`. The catch is that `Root.path("id")` returns an instance of `Path`, which does not allow further joins.

The trick is to use a 'fake' join with the `id` field like so: `eventOrderLine.join("id").join("event")`

`eventOrderLine.get("id").get("event")` would likely work just as well, but it wouldn't allow you to specify the join type.

Answer (score 0):

first try to get the property `id` of `EventOrderLine` entity and then join. So, it would be -

```
Root eventOrderLine = criteriaQuery.from(EventOrderLine.class);
Join orderLine = eventOrderLine.get("id").join("orderLine")
```

Comment: Get returns a path which in turn doesn't have a join method